# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 xcode 13.4

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arm64, build-error, xcode13

I have a Xcode Project was build from Unity with

Unity 2020.3.40f1
Xcode 13.4

After build iOS project from Unity, i run `pod install` in Xcode project folder.
Then in Unity-Iphone > Unity-Iphone > UnityFramework:

- Enable Bitcode: No
- Other Linker Flags: delete $(inherited)

When build project, i got that error log:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALUtils", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALPrivacySettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MARewardedAd", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityAdManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAAppOpenAd", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityAdManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAInterstitialAd", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityAdManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MARewardedInterstitialAd", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityAdManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAAdFormat", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityAdManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALSdkSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityAdManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAAdView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityAdManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALSdk", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAUnityAdManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does is missing library or SDK? I've been looking for a few workarounds but it doesn't work.

Fix this error for successfully building app.